# Change HTML name attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, element, rename

On the press of a `div` (which I made into a `button` with other code) I would like the following code:

```
<div id="w1" name="w1-0" onclick="weekclick(id)">1<br /></div>
```

...for the name to change from `name="w1-0"` to `name="w1-1"`

I'm using the following JavaScript:

```
function weekclick(id)
{    
 document.getElementById(id).input.name = "w1-1";
}
```

When I `alert` the id's `name` attribute, it says it is undefined. What do?

Comment: Div elements do not have a `name` attribute, and DivElementNode objects do not have an `input` property. Div elements are designed to be generic containers, if you want a button, then use a `<button>`.

Comment: [7.5.4 Grouping elements: the DIV and SPAN elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4)

Comment: What is the `name` attribute used for? What's it's purpose on the page?

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's used to pass values to the server (in the format name=value), via GET or POST methods on a FORM.

Answer (score 22):

see code below:

```
<div id="w1" name='w1-0' onclick="weekclick(id)">1<br /></div>
<div onclick="weekclick('w1');">click me</div>​

<script type="text/javascript">
function weekclick(id) {    
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("name","w1-1");
}​
</script>
```

link to fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TH9C2/

(remove the alert line from the fiddle - it is just there to show you that it works)

Comment: "fiddle attached" Why not "*See code below (with link to fiddle).*"?

Comment: changed the answer - satisfied now? :)

Answer (score 2):

first of all change your call in the html to this
user `this.id` and not just id:

```
<div id="w1" name='w1-0' onclick="weekclick(this.id)">1<br /></div>
```

than make your js like this (remove .input and use setAttribute):

```
function weekclick(id) {    
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('name', 'w1-1');
}
```

**EDIT**
or you you change your call in html to this:

```
weekclick(this)
```

and your js function have to be like this:

```
function weekclick(domElement) {    
    domElement.setAttribute('name', 'w1-1');
}
```