# How to pass value to directive attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text box, a submit button and a directive.

```
<input type="text" />  
<input type="submit" />
<my-dir name=""></my-dir>
```

Every time I type something in the box and submit, I hope the string can be passed to the "name" attribute of my-dir. How to achieve it?

Comment: Not using Angular if possible. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change HTML name element using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447439/change-html-name-element-using-javascript)

Comment: *"directives"* are an Angular concept. Do you just mean *"custom element"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be any problems using `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementsByTagName`. Here's a quick example...

```css
my-dir:after {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: attr(name);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="document.querySelector('my-dir').setAttribute('name', this.text.value); return false">
    <input name="text" type="text" />  
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<my-dir name=""></my-dir>
```